# systemVerilog: affecting local scope of a variable from a task

Tags: task, system-verilog

All,

I'd like to use a task to change the content of local scope variables.

Here the piece of code that does not work as I intend:

```
  module dummy;
   int  test = 100; //global scope var, I don't want to change this one
   task assignTest;
      test =123; //should change the content of local scope var named test
   endtask // forceV

   initial
     begin  
       begin  
         int test; //I want to affect this variable
         assignTest;
         $display(">>local test=%d", test);
       end    
      $display(">>global test=%d", test);
     end
```

Here is what I got as a result:

```
>>local test=          0
>>global test=        123
```

So I conclude that the task has no effect on the local variable as I wish.
Any ideas on how to implement this?

thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

A few ways:

1. Use a connect via port so calling `assignTest` becomes `assignTest(test)`. There are three ways to define `assignTest`:

   ```
   task assignTest(output int test);
   task assignTest(inout int test); 
   task automatic assignTest(ref int test);
   ```
2. Hard code the scope the local `test` within the task. This requires naming your scopes. Example:

   ```
   int  test = 100;
   task assignTest;
     init_scope.local_scope.test = 123;
   endtask // forceV

   initial begin : init_scope
     begin : local_scope
       int test;
       assignTest;
       $display(">>local test=%d", test);
     end    
     $display(">>global test=%d", test);
   end
   ```

Working examples [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/WJP)

I recommend the port options as they are m ore flexible and reusable. Which of the three styles depend on the design/implementation requirements.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that we could label scopes. That's neat! Unfortunately the real application is a little more complex than the example. I have to extend existing checkers with additional messages without changing their interfaces. So using new ports would represent trouble. I wish systemVerilog had something equivalent to python decorators.

Comment: Might be to late for current project, however in the future you should look into `bind` see Section 23.11 _Binding auxiliary code to scopes or instances_ in [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)